# Problems with KeyEvent

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I have a panel just with a `Jtextfield` that only accept numbers. So, when I press enter will load a user profile. this is just to see his profile.

What I want: When I press ENTER again all the profile will be cleared, and when I press the numbers and press ENTER again and load the profile again and again...

My problem: I pressed enter and the profile is cleared (Ok all fine), but when I enter the number and press the ENTER, The numbers are cleared and nothing happens, it is like a loop in `matriculaTxt.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { ... }`

Sorry for my bad English.

```
private void matriculaTxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                             
    String matricula = matriculaTxt.getText().trim();

    if (!matricula.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        matriculaTxt.setText("");
    } else {
        fc = new FrequenciaController();
        matriculaTxt.setEditable(false);
        matriculaTxt.requestFocus();
        fc.checkinManual(Integer.parseInt(matricula));
    }

    // the problem is here.
    matriculaTxt.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                nomeTxt.setText("");
                statusTxt.setText("");
                imageLb.setIcon(null);
                acessoLabel.setText("");
                matriculaTxt.setText("");
                observacaoTxt.setText("");
                System.err.println("ENTER");
                PendenciasTableModel ptm = new PendenciasTableModel();// vazio
                pendenciasTabela.setModel(ptm);
                matriculaTxt.setEditable(true);
                matriculaTxt.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

What I wanted to do was simple. The user types in the text field their numbers, pressing ENTER: their data are loaded. `requestFocus()` into the text field and it will not be editable anymore, because when I press Enter again the field will be editable but everything will be deleted, and so on.

Comment: What I wanted to do was simple. 
The user types in the text field their numbers, pressing ENTER: their data are loaded. 
requestFocus () into the text field and it will not be editable anymore, because when I press Enter again the field will be editable but everything will be deleted, and so on.

Comment: That is confusing to me. Please try to clarify some more. 1) what are your exact requirements. 2) How exactly is your current code not working well.

Comment: my exact requirements is, when i press ENTER again all data will be cleaned for a new data be inserted and so on.
the code works fine, but doenst do what i want.

If i change the KeyEvent.VK_ENTER to VK_SPACE, works fine, but i dont want SPACE, what i want is ENTER. =)

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you should never use a KeyListener for this sort of thing. Consider instead using either a JFormattedTextField or using a DocumentFilter to prevent non-numeric entry. Next, you should use an ActionLIstener to have the JTextField accept and react to the user's pressing the Enter key.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> my exact requirements is, when i press ENTER again all data will be cleaned for a new data be inserted.

Why not simply have in your JTextField's ActionLIstener:

```
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // get the text
    JTextComponent textComp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
    String text = textComp.getText();

    // do what you want with text here

    // clear the text
    textComp.setText("");
 }
```

Again, you should not use a KeyListener for any of this stuff.

---

**Edit 2**
If you want a multi-state action listener, one that reacts differently depending on the state of the program, then give it some if blocks to allow it to react to the state of the JTextField. If the field is empty, do one thing, if it has numbers, do another, if it has text, show a warning and clear it:

```
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // get the text
    JTextComponent textComp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
    String text = textComp.getText().trim(); // trim it to rid it of white space

    if (text.isEmpty()) {
       // code to show a profile 
       return;  // to exit this method
    } 

    // if we're here, the field is not empty

    if (!text.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        // show a warning message here
    } else {
      // numeric only data present
      // do action for this state

   }
   // clear the text
   textComp.setText("");
}
```

The key again is to not use a KeyListener, but rather to "listen" for the enter key press with the ActionListener *only*, but to react differently depending on the state of the program, here likely being depending on what content is present in the JTextField.

Comment: Assuming the data was already loaded in the act of putting the numbers and typed enter without having to push a button.

Comment: @user2824425: JTextFields will use ActionListeners just fine. No JButton needed.

Comment: You are rigth, but ,how can I make: A screen with 1 text field, which to put the user id and hit ENTER, display a table with all his records. And again when I hit Enter to delete everything that I can put the record it again? Doing all of these actions in the same text field.

Comment: @user2824425: ??? You would do it just as I specified in my answer above. I thought that the answer above addressed just this concern. Again, the same ActionListener will have different actions depending on the evaluations of the if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem that the `KeyListener` it'll not trigger, it will not execute the code inside it, because whenever you press `ENTER` it will trigger the `matriculaTxtActionPerformed` then declared the `KeyLister`, so the `ENTER` will effect it.